# How to properly configure spring-security with vaadin14 to handle 2 entry points - keyclaok and DB

Tags: spring-security, vaadin, vaadin14

I have a vaadin14 application that I want to enable different types of authentication mechanisms on different url paths. One is a test url, where authentication should use DB, and the other is the production url that uses keycloak.

I was able to get each authentication mechanism to work separately, but once I try to put both, I get unexpected results.

In both cases, I get login page, but the authentication doesn't work correctly. Here's my security configuration, what am I doing wrong?

```js
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfiguration {


  @Configuration
  @Order(2)
  public static class DBAuthConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_FAILURE_URL = "/login?error";
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/login";

    /**
     * Require login to access internal pages and configure login form.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      // Not using Spring CSRF here to be able to use plain HTML for the login page
      http.csrf().disable()

        // Register our CustomRequestCache, that saves unauthorized access attempts, so
        // the user is redirected after login.
        .requestCache().requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())

        // Restrict access to our application.
        .and().antMatcher("/test**").authorizeRequests()

        // Allow all flow internal requests.
        .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()

        // Allow all requests by logged in users.
        .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")

        // Configure the login page.
        .and().formLogin().loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll().loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
        .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)

        // Configure logout
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

      Properties users = null;
      try {
        users = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("users.properties");
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      UserDetails user =
        User.withUsername("user")
        .password("{noop}password")
        .roles("ACTOR")
        .build();

      return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    /**
     * Allows access to static resources, bypassing Spring security.
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
      web.ignoring().antMatchers(
        // Vaadin Flow static resources
        "/VAADIN/**",
        // the standard favicon URI
        "/favicon.ico",
        // the robots exclusion standard
        "/robots.txt",
        // web application manifest
        "/manifest.webmanifest",
        "/sw.js",
        "/offline-page.html",
        // icons and images
        "/icons/**",
        "/images/**",
        // (development mode) static resources
        "/frontend/**",
        // (development mode) webjars
        "/webjars/**",
        // (development mode) H2 debugging console
        "/h2-console/**",
        // (production mode) static resources
        "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**",
        "/resources/**");
    }
  }

  @Order(1)
  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
  public static class AppKeycloakSecurity extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
      AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

      KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
        = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
      keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
        new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
      auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
      return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }


    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
      return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
        new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      super.configure(http);

      http.httpBasic().disable();
      http.formLogin().disable();
      http.anonymous().disable();
      http.csrf().disable();
      http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

      http
        .antMatcher("/prod**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("actor");

      http
        .logout()
        .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
        .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
      http
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class);
      http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
      http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you make a request to `"/prod"`? Your current ant matcher will match a request to `"/prod"`, but not `"/prod/other"`. Do you perhaps mean to write `.antMatcher("/prod/**")` and `.antMatcher("/test/**")`?

Comment: Thank you @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, no it's a simple one page application. So changing my ant matcher doesn't have an impact here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigating within a Vaadin UI will change the URL in your browser, but it will not necessarily create a browser request to that exact URL, effectively bypassing the access control defined by Spring security for that URL. As such, Vaadin is really not suited for the request URL-based security approach that Spring provides. For this issue alone you could take a look at my add-on [Spring Boot Security for Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/spring-boot-security-for-vaadin) which I specifically created to close the gap between Spring security and Vaadin.

But while creating two distinct Spring security contexts based on the URL is fairly easy, this - for the same reason - will not work well or at all with Vaadin. And that's something even my add-on couldn't help with.

**Update:** As combining both security contexts is an option for you, I can offer the following solution (using my add-on):
Starting from the [Keycloak example](https://gitlab.com/codecamp-de/vaadin-security-spring-demo/-/tree/keycloak), you would have to do the following:

1. Change `WebSecurityConfig` to also add your DB-based `AuthenticationProvider`. Adding your `UserDetailsService` should still be enough. Make sure to give every user a suitable role.
2. You have to remove this line from `application.properties`: `codecamp.vaadin.security.standard-auth.enabled = false`
   This will re-enable the standard login without Keycloak via a Vaadin view.
3. Adapt the `KeycloakRouteAccessDeniedHandler` to ignore all test views that shouldn't be protected by Keycloak.

I already [prepared all this in Gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/codecamp-de/vaadin-security-spring-demo/-/tree/so-67814818) and removed everything not important for the main point of this solution. See the individual commits and their diffs to also help focus in on the important bits.

Comment: Thank you @p12t I'll check the plugin. I'm wondering if there are alternatives to spring-security that can work with vaadin and fulfil my requirements? Would Apache Shiro be of any help?

Comment: I think the difficult part is the integration with Vaadin, which Shiro hasn't either. Quote from Shiro: "It greatly simplifies how you secure web applications based on simple URL pattern matching and filter chain definitions." Looks like the same approach (and the same problems) as with Spring Security.

Comment: One possible approach: Merge both WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters. Things to consider here: Users could only be authenticated via Keycloak or DB, not both. Users would get the login for whichever context they access first. And you would need roles to separate both prod and test contexts. Switching from prod to test eg. would mean logging out and logging back in; or use different browsers to get separate sessions. In that case my add-on could help. If that's an option for you, let me know, then I can provide a few more details in my answer.

Comment: These assumptions match my requirements accurately, How can I merge both WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters while having different mechanisms? It would be great if you can provide me with more details. Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help, the solution works perfectly. I remember that I investigated your plugin before starting my task and I found very useful information, but now you gave me another reason to keep using it :)

Comment: You're welcome. It's always good to see that the effort that goes into creating something is helpful to someone (besides oneself). If you don't mind, please also drop a comment on the add-on's page. It would help to see that people are actually successfully using it.